# Cannot locate element using Selenium Python

Tags: python, html, selenium, python-requests

So I'm trying to locate this element and click it using Selenium. I'm using the following code:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/label/text() and contains(., 'Upload CSV')]"))).click()
```

I essentially just copied the XPATH of the 'Upload CSV' text.

Here's a screenshot of the HTML:
[image: Element]

Very new to Selenium/HTML so any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try (adapt it to your EC condition):

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "// label[contains(text(), 'Upload CSV')]")
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@class='bulk-upload-buttons/label and contains(., 'Upload CSV')]"))).click()
```